# Wordpress cron hooks - same callback for completely different action?

Tags: wp-cron

I am trying to better understand how `Wordpress` deals with `cron jobs` so that I can better figure out how to create some custom jobs that send emails based on single occurrence events, like `lesson started` or `lesson webinar started`.

**In my case, I want to have emails sent to users when I have certain content that becomes available.** The availability is based on a date field that I have as custom meta for a custom post type.

So imagine a bunch of courses and lessons. When a lesson opens up, I want that event to trigger sending emails to users with access to the lesson. Likewise, when a lesson's webinar starts, I also want to trigger emails.

Right now, for the case of a lesson drip date, I react to a `save_post_membrepressrule` hook that passes `$rule_id` and schedule a cron job to send an email on the drip release date for the lesson. I do that in the hook as

```
    // save meta for lesson if this rule is 'single_sfwd-lessons' and has fixed drip
function my_save_post_membrepressrule_hook ($rule_id)
{    
    // bunch of checks first
   if ( (isset($_POST['_mepr_rules_type']) AND $_POST['_mepr_rules_type'] == 'single_sfwd-lessons')
        AND ( isset($_POST['_mepr_rules_drip_enabled']) AND $_POST['_mepr_rules_drip_enabled'] == 'on')
        AND ( isset($_POST['_mepr_rules_drip_after_fixed']) AND $_POST['_mepr_rules_drip_after_fixed'] != '')  ) 
   {
      // we have fixed drip date for a given lesson
      $lesid = $_POST['_mepr_rules_content'];
      $course_id = (int) learndash_get_course_id($lesid);

      // now set notification if rule is in future

      $lesdate = $_POST['_mepr_rules_drip_after_fixed'];
      $lesdate = new DateTime($lesdate, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
      $current_date = new DateTime();
      $current_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ));
      
      if ($lesdate > $current_date) 
      {      
          $notifs = get_notifications( 'lesson_started', $course_id, $lesson_id);
          if ( ! $notifs ) {
             return;
          }

          // what memberships are tied to this drip rule?
        
          global $wpdb;
          $memberships = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT access_condition FROM wp_mepr_rule_access_conditions WHERE access_type = 'membership' AND access_operator = 'is' AND rule_id = '$rule_id'");

          foreach ($memberships as $membership) {
              $membership_id = $membership->access_condition
              $wpdb->query("SET time_zone = 'UTC'");
              $activeusers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM wp_mepr_transactions WHERE status IN('confirmed','complete') AND (expires_at >= NOW() OR expires_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AND product_id = '$membership_id'");

              // likely just one notification post for a given notification type, but use loop just in case
              foreach ($notifs as $notif)
              {
                 foreach ($activeusers as $activeuser) 
                 {
                    if ((int) $activeuser->user_id != 0)
                    {
                       // delete what currently is set for these users for this lesson/membership combo
                    
                       delete_user_meta($activeuser->user_id, 'ld_sent_notification_lesson_started'.$notif->ID . '_' . $lesson_id . '_'. $membership_id);
                    }
                 }
                       
                 // see if we already have cron job to send email for this lesson drip, so we can remove in case we changed the drip date
                 if ( wp_next_scheduled( 'my_custom_crons', [ $notif->ID, 'lesson_started', $membership_id, $course_id, $lesson_id ] ) )             
                 {
                    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'my_custom_crons', [ $notif->ID, 'lesson_started', $membership_id, $course_id, $lesson_id ] );
                 }
                 wp_schedule_single_event( $lesdate->getTimeStamp(), 'my_custom_crons', [ $notif->ID, 'lesson_started', $membership_id, $course_id, $lesson_id ] );
              } // end notif loop
           } // end memberships loop
        } // if date in future
    } // if drip rule for lesson
}
```

So this sets up single event cron in WP named `my_custom_crons`. I have similar logic for a `webinar_started` event, as well as `webinat_starts_in_onehour` event for a given lesson.

To react to this hook, I have

```
add_action( 'my_custom_crons','my_custom_crons', 99, 5 );
function my_custom_crons( $notif, $notification_type, $membership_id, $course_id, $lesson_id) {

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("SET time_zone = 'UTC'");
    $activeusers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM wp_mepr_transactions WHERE status IN('confirmed','complete') AND (expires_at >= NOW() OR expires_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AND product_id = '$membership_id'");
    if ( empty( $activeusers ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // ok, we have users that are active
    foreach ( $activeusers as $activeuser ) {
        $user_id = absint( $activeuser->user_id );
        if ($user_id != 0) {
            // bunch of checking
            // get notification message for notification type (lessons tarted, or webinar started)
            // then send the emails

        }
    }

    // clear the job (but this not needed?)
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_custom_crons', array(
                $notif->ID,
                $notification_type, 
                $course_id,
                $membership_id,
                $lesson_id,
    ));
}
```

All seems to be working in terms of cron being set up. If I run `wp cron event list` after adding a Membrepress Drip Rule for a lesson, I see the `my_custom_crons` job scheduled:

```
my_custom_crons| 2021-11-03 20:01:00 |16 hours 1 minute| Non-repeating
```

**But what happens if I have multiple lessons and multiple events I want to use for email triggers, all with various dates? As mentioned, I might have `lesson_started` and `lesson_webinar_started` event for various lessons. So will my current approach work, or will various events for various lessons all triggered at different times, all using my one cron hook's logic, interfere with one another?**

Just not seeing bigger picture of how I should be doing this...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not quite.

When you say this:

```php
wp_schedule_single_event( $sent_on, 'my_custom_cron', [ $notif_id, $notif_name, $membership_id, $lesson_id ] );
```

You are essentially saying is when the current time passes `$sent_on`, do:

```php
do_action( 'my_custom_cron', [ $notif_id, $notif_name, $membership_id, $lesson_id ] );
```

Cron jobs are just a TODO note to fire an action with some arguments in the future. That's all they are, the action works exactly the same as any other action/hook.

So:

> But what happens if I have multiple lessons and multiple events I want to use for email triggers, all with various dates?

Then you'll have multiple scheduled cron jobs with different arguments.

It will only send emails for all lessons if you built a function that sends emails for all lessons and added it to that hook. That's an extremely obvious and deliberate thing to do, I think you would know if you had done that due to the special effort needed to fetch all lessons and send emails.

> As mentioned, I might have lesson_started and lesson_webinar_started event for various lessons. So will my current approach work, or will various events for various lessons all triggered at different times, all using my one cron hook's logic, interfere with one another?

Did you build them to interfere with eachother? If so yes! If not then no.

---

If you schedule a cron job 5 times for a hook, that hook will be fired 5 times. If you give it different arguments each time, the hook will fire with different arguments each time. It's a queue. I understand the anxiety and uncertainty around this but a little investigation and common sense reveals it's unfounded. Likewise some quick tests would demonstrate it's not the case.

The one thing that I will point out though is the `wp_clear_scheduled_hook` call, it doesn't make sense. It's like declaring you will not go to the store on Monday just after you get home from the store. The cron job has already fired, it's too late, and it's a non-repeating one time single cron job so there's nothing to clear in the future.

That entire loop makes no sense, that's not how `wp_schedule_single_event` works, it would match the first time then there'd be nothing on the follow up iterations of the loop as you've already cleared it. `wp_schedule_single_event` schedules a *single* event, not a repeating event.

Comment: Thanks for the insight as always. When you talk about the loop not making sense and "$notif->ID isn't what was passed as an argument so it would never match anything", what exactly do you mean? I edited my post, included more of the actual code to show more specifically what I am doing.  thanks

Comment: you're asking it to clear out scheduled actions that have a set of arguments. For some reason it's wrapped in a loop and called over and over again, which makes no sense. If you have 5 active users it'll try to clear the same thing 5 times, why 5? Isn't 1 enough? The first time it gets called it'll be cleared. But even then, why would you need to clear it at all? You called `wp_schedule_single_event`, `wp_schedule_SINGLE_event`, singular, once, one time, not a repeating cron job, so _there is nothing to clear_, the event you scheduled has already happened, it doesn't stick around forever

Comment: If I gave you a todo list of one off tasks, would I need to add additional todo items labelled "cross off previous todo item when done"? And would having the same todo item 5 times in the list mean that when I do it it happens 5 times for a total of 25 times? No, that wouldn't make sense, single event cron jobs are the same

Comment: Hi, ok, I moved that wp_clear_scheduled_hook out of the user loop (shown above in edit). And reading what you say, I guess I should just remove it.  So now, if I run wp_schedule_single_event for two different lessons, and two different start times, my `my_custom_crons` hook will run for each, using the provided args, so that each single recurrence job will be handled individually? In this case, shouldn't I see `my_custom_crons` twice in output of `wp cron event list`? Thanks!

Comment: yes, there is no reason to keep it, and no because as soon as you schedule an event your moved clear schedule eliminates it on the next request, which is why it should have been removed

Comment: it's also possible you did not pass unique arguments and scheduled it within 10 minutes of another with the same arguments. I'd suggest reading https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/

Comment: Ok, reading this "Note that scheduling an event to occur within 10 minutes of an existing event with the same action hook will be ignored unless you pass unique $args values for each scheduled event." seems all should work as I need, since the args are unique each time. Need to do more checking... Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: i ran a quick check scheduling a made up hook, as long as the args are different it'll appear multiple times in the WP CLI output, although each one had a slightly different time which might have skewed it. WP CLI is great but it could use more information, like the arguments etc. WP Crontrol might give more granular detail

Comment: I seem to have things working - thanks for the patience! I suppose this brings up an obvious question - about how to ideally run these sorts of crons. As I do it now, a cron is always created when I set a drip date for a lesson, then when the cron is run, it checks if there are enrolled users for whom to send the email. I suppose another way is to only create the cron if there are users, but then I need to have additional logic to listen for users added and see if the cron should be set up. I figured the way I am doing it now might be more resources intensive, but I figured would be easier...

Comment: whichever way works, at this point it has more to do with the mechanics of how your application is intended to work rather than how WP Cron itself works

Comment: Actually I am noticing something odd. I just checked and see that `wp cron event list` showed 4 entries with `my_custom_crons`. Two are for two memberships same lesson, and the other 2 are for same two memberships but different lesson. One pair was set to run in a minute, the other pair set to run a week from now. The two that were set for a minute ran, but so did the others that are not set to run for a week. So the two entries in the event list that were set to run in a minute ran, but for some reason I can't figure out, the other two ran as well. Any ideas what could cause that?

Comment: Maybe when using a single event, and the name is same for multiple events, wp runs them all, and then I need to do internal check in my cron hook to make sure I really should let it run?

Comment: the arguments are different so use the arguments, they're just actions/hooks

Comment: But then it amounts to doing the sort of checking that WP core should be doing. Not sure why it would fire all 4 hooks. I am going to step through the WP core and see where its logic is.

Comment: of course it would fire all 4 hooks, you scheduled that hook to run 4 times, each with different arguments, so it will run 4 times. I think you're expecting more smarts and intuition from WP than there is and overcomplicating things. It is literally just a way to say "fire this hook with these arguments but in 10 or more minutes". `wp_schedule_single_event` runs it once, `wp_schedule_event` runs it every X minutes based on a recurring schedule until it's cleared. Events with the same arguments less than 10 minutes apart are merged, that's it, there's no more to it than that.

Comment: WP Cron is a todo list of hooks and arguments to fire, when WP fires the hook it crosses it off the list. If it's a recurring event it schedules a new one for the next time it's supposed to run. It'll check if any events are due now at the end of each request, attempt to run them, then clear them off the list. I think you're greatly overcomplicating this, that is the logic in its entirety

Comment: I thought WP internally used the logic "fire these hooks at the time they are set to run". That is what I am not understanding. If two instances of the `my_custom_crons` queue are set one week from now, why would their args be passed to the hook prior to that time? Anyway, I can overcome it, just a bit odd, that in my hook, I have to then run a bunch of queries to see what the time stamp (drip date) is of the corresponding args, when all that was done in the first place when running wp_schedule_single_event upon the drip rule creation.

Comment: Why would they be passed prior to that time? That makes no sense and I've never claimed as such. There is one queue, a queue of hooks with arguments and due dates/times. I also have no idea what you mean by a drip date. Anyway, does my answer answer your question? If so could you mark it as accepted?

Comment: You can accept an answer via the tick under the voting controls, I'd recommend going back through your questions to do this where appropriate, you've asked a lot of questions but most have no accepted answer, that's a lot of potential reputation points that weren't handed out to the people who tried to help

Comment: Yes, of course, accepted. I am starting to think I am having this issue because I am overriding WP-Cron and using crontab on MAC. So in that crontab I run `for hook in $(wp cron event list --next_run_relative=now --fields=hook --format=ids); 
  do wp cron event run "$hook" --path=/mysite;
done;` But even then I thought `--next_run_relative=now` would get the needed ones. Anyway, really appreciate your help and patience!

Comment: I just disabled my MAC crontab and reenabled Wp-Cron and things are working as expected. So now question is, when disabling Wp-Cron.php  how to specify `wp cron event run` so that it only runs the relevant hooks...

Comment: Ok, all working now via wp cron now that I have my crontab running `wp cron event run --due-now` Not sure why I was even using a for loop through all the crons in the first place... Thanks again

Comment: @Brian no I don't mean do you agree it is the correct answer, I mean can you mark this as the correct/accepted answer if it answers your question? It's the check mark underneath the voting controls, you have to click on the button. This isn't a discussion forum, you're meant to mark the best correct answer as correct by clicking the check mark so it turns green. That's how the site knows which questions have been answered and gives out reputation points